# Different ways of Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, cloud, containers

Different ways of Kubernetes deployment?

1.Kops 
2.Terraform
3.Kubeadm

Which is the best one to pick for both on-premises and cloud? And please point me to best resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/) is the list of different ways to deploy kubernetes.

[kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) are pretty good ways to deploy on-premise kubernetes.

For cloud deployments, you could look at the following k8s solutions:

- [Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)
- [Microsoft Azure AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/)
- [Google GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)
- [DigitalOcean kubernetes](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/)
- [Red Hat OpenShift Online](https://www.openshift.com/products/online/)

Answer (score 0):

Use kubespray. It supports on premise as well as cloud

Check kubespray github repo